# How to escape text containing single quote from properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**I've encountered an issue with thymeleaf template that I have no clue to fix it.**

**I am trying to read text from .properties file for thymeleaf templates.**

Lets say, the line from property file looks like this:

```
line = This should show '+variable+' value.
```

Using Javascript, I have created a div like this:

```
$('#bar').stop().hover(function (evt) {
    $('<div id="line-text">[[${environment.get('line')}]]</div>');
}
```

The outcome is given below :

```
This should show &#39;+variable+&#39; value.
```

and I need this:

```
This should show '+variable+' value.
```

How to solve this ?

**Edit :**

*I've tried to escape with the characters like backslash, double and single quotes. Then also it's not working.*

Comment: Does using `[({environment.get('line')})]` (which is an unescaped JavaScript expression `[(...)]`)  instead of `[[{environment.get('line')}]]` work?